# submit php form to google docs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is my html form submitting using jquery

```
<form target="_self" onsubmit="" action="javascript: postContactToGoogle()" method="post" onsubmit="">
        <span id="form-error"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['alert'])){ echo $_SESSION['alert']; unset($_SESSION['alert']);} ?></span>
        <div class="form-group">
        <p class="no-margin bottom5">YOUR NAME (required)</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p class="no-margin bottom5">YOUR EMAIL (required)</p>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p class="no-margin bottom5">MESSAGE</p>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message"></textarea>  
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Send</button>
       <div style="width: 100%; display: block; float: right; padding-top: 15px;">
        <div class="requestSubmited" style="display:none; text-align: center;">Your request has been sent!</div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my jquery

```
function postContactToGoogle(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/a/mapplinks.com/forms/d/1r3SISt7ocWE32s7LJxBOOteMeMV-JTy166pH87hxwF4/formResponse",
            data: {"entry.2028011364" : name, "entry.1745855979" : email, "entry.919224434": message},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            statusCode: {
                0: function (){

                   alert("saved0");
                    //Success message
                },
                200: function (){
                   alert("saved");
                    //Success Message
                }
            }
        });


}
```

This is my form and jquery which i have been using.Im getting response 0 but google form is not getting updated.Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Just follow that guide:

https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000

This will helps.

Comment: While this web page might have the answer, it's better to actually post code in your answer.